# Get Woocommerce to Manage Stock as a default

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

**Is there a hook that would allow setting the Inventory > Manage Stock checkbox in woocommerce globally?**

All my products are single item quantity, so it seems pretty counter-D.R.Y to always have to remember to check it, especially for other employees.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A little late, but here's how for anyone else needing to do this... I found most of this code somewhere else, but I don't have the link anymore to where I found it. Tweaked it a little and this is what I ended up with (add to functions.php):

```
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'wc_default_variation_stock_quantity' );
function wc_default_variation_stock_quantity() {
  global $pagenow, $woocommerce;

  $default_stock_quantity = 1;
  $screen = get_current_screen();

  if ( ( $pagenow == 'post-new.php' || $pagenow == 'post.php' || $pagenow == 'edit.php' ) && $screen->post_type == 'product' ) {

    ?>
<!-- uncomment this if jquery if it hasn't been included
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
-->
    <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        if ( !jQuery( '#_manage_stock' ).attr('checked') ) {
          jQuery( '#_manage_stock' ).attr('checked', 'checked');
        }
        if ( '' === jQuery( '#_stock' ).val() ) {
          jQuery( '#_stock' ).val(<?php echo $default_stock_quantity; ?>);
        }
    });
    </script>
    <?php
  }
}
```

Answer (score 12):

Although this is *quite* late, since you asked about a hook: although there doesn't appear to be a hook, action or function specifically for turning on the `Manage Stock` option, you can still hook into the post save function and auto-enable it that way, since it is just a post_meta value:

```
add_action('save_post', 'myWoo_savePost', 10, 2);

function myWoo_savePost($postID, $post) {
    if (isset($post->post_type) && $post->post_type == 'product') {

        update_post_meta($post->ID, '_manage_stock', 'yes');
    }
}
```

Note that stock levels will always default to 0, so you may also want to add the line:

```
update_post_meta($post->ID, '_stock', '1');
```

...which will update your stock quantity to 1. Do be aware that this will happen *every time* a product is saved, though.

I'm unsure as to whether this has knock-on effects elsewhere in WooCommerce for larger stock quantities, but as you're dealing with single-quantity items, I'd guess you're probably okay.

**Update (with $update):**

As of Wordpress 3.7, a third parameter was added to [`save_post`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/save_post/) so you can easily tell if it's a new post being created or an existing post being updated. As such, you can fire the function above *only* when creating a new post (which is arguably the desired effect):

```
add_action('save_post_product', 'myWoo_savePost', 10, 3);

function myWoo_savePost($postID, $post, $update) {
    if (!$update) {
        //  $update is false if we're creating a new post
        update_post_meta($post->ID, '_manage_stock', 'yes');
        update_post_meta($post->ID, '_stock', '1');
    }
}
```

*(Thanks to [Dylan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15908411/get-woocommerce-to-manage-stock-as-a-default/25485005#comment67019876_25485005) for the reminder about post-type specific saves)*

Comment: big thank you for this code, just great! the only problem with it, is that even when trying to increase the qty, it saves as 1 product only. But ok for now :)

Comment: @Iggy Yup - as mentioned, it will carry out that hook every time the product is saved. You may want to add a conditional in there to check if it's a new post. I'll update my answer now.

Comment: You are genius! you may release a plugin like that, really useful. I've even added some css to hide qty if there i only one product in stock. `/* product page, hide qty for 1 product */
.single-product div.product form.cart .quantity .qty {
 margin-right: 1em;
}
.single-product div.product form.cart .button {
 float: none;
}
.single-product div.product form.cart .quantity .qty[max="1"] {
 visibility: hidden;
 display: none;
}`

Comment: This is much nicer than using JavaScript. From WordPress 3.7 you can also use the dynamic `save_post_{$post->post_type}` hook which would translate to `save_post_product`. You can then remove the post_type conditional.

Comment: @Dylan Good point - I've updated my answer. I always forget about that!

Answer (score 0):

Woocommerce now has it's own hook for saving a product. For a simple product it's `woocommerce_process_product_meta_simple`.

Before updating the meta, we should first check that the `_manage_stock` is empty i.e. the checkbox has not been checked, so that it only triggers on products which have not already been set.

Then toggle the manage stock and set the default stock number.

```
function manage_stock_default( $post_id ) {
    if (empty($_POST['_manage_stock'])) {
      update_post_meta($post_id, '_manage_stock', 'yes');
      update_post_meta($post_id, '_stock', '1');
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_process_product_meta_simple', 'manage_stock_default');
```

Comment: also works, but only after saving the product