# WooCommerce product variations: Auto enable Manage Stock and set stock quantity

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

On Admin Woocommerce product pages, for variable products, on "Variations" settings, for all product variations, I would like to have **Manage Stock** option enabled by default with the **Stock Quantity** option set to **1**.

Using [Get Woocommerce to Manage Stock as a default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15908411/get-woocommerce-to-manage-stock-as-a-default/25485005#25485005) answer code, I am able to do it for the default inventory tab *(for the parent variable product)*.

I even tried [Woocommerce: Creating variations - Manage stock checked by default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64153300/woocommerce-creating-variations-manage-stock-checked-by-default/64155230#64155230) answer code, but it didn't worked form me.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For info, `woocommerce_product_variation_get_manage_stock` hook doesn't exist anymore.

Based on jQuery code, the following will enable **Manage Stock** and will set **Stock Quantity** to **1**, for all product variations:

```
add_action( 'admin_footer', 'custom_admin_product_variations_js' );
function custom_admin_product_variations_js() {
    global $post_type;

    if ( 'product' === $post_type ) :
    ?><script type='text/javascript'>
    jQuery( function($) {
        $('#variable_product_options').on( 'change', function(){
            $('input.variable_manage_stock').each( function(){
                if( ! $(this).is(':checked') ){
                    $(this).attr('checked', 'checked').closest('div').find('.wc_input_stock').val(1);
                }
            });
        });
    });
    </script><?php
    endif;
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of the active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

Comment: Thank you for the solution. It is working great as expected. But the client wants solution without using JQuery. Do you have any idea of doing this without JQuery?

Answer (score 0):

In case if you only want to checked, variation manage stock and do not want to change stock quantity, similarly if you want that it should be edited on variation level in case product level manage stock is no checked

Following is the code (Edited version of above posted answer by @LoicTheAztec )

```
/* Manage Stock Checked By Default On New Product */
if (jQuery("body").hasClass("post-new-php") && jQuery("body").hasClass("post-type-product")) {
 //By default check product level manage stock  
 jQuery("#_manage_stock").prop('checked',true);

 jQuery('#variable_product_options').on( 'change', function(){
    //condition in case product level manage stock is checked 
   if(jQuery("#_manage_stock").prop('checked') == true){
        jQuery('input.variable_manage_stock').each( function(){
            if( ! jQuery(this).is(':checked') ){
                jQuery(this).attr('checked', 'checked');
            }
        });
      }
  });
}
/* END:: Manage Stock Checked By Default On New Product */
```